# How to search with optional data and list data in ElasticsearchRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using `spring-data-elasticsearch` and I have a class as follows,

```
@Document(indexName = "sample")
class Sample {

   @Id
   private String id;
   private String n_id;
   private String b_ref;
   private String r_ref;
   private Status status;
}
```

Above is persisted to `elasticsearch`. And I have the following method to find data in it.

```
List<Sample> getAll(String n_id, Optional<String> b_ref, Optional<String> r_ref, List<Status> statuses);
```

But the challenge I am facing is I have 2 `Optional` fields and 1 `List` field that need to check if `contains` the status. I tried multiple ways in `ElasticsearchRepository` but none of them worked.

How can I build the query for the above scenario?

Comment: what would it mean if an empty Optional is passed into your method? Shouldit not be considered in the search or should the corresponding field in the stored document be empty?

Comment: Yes, so when searching if `Optional` is empty it should not consider that field. If the `Optional` is not empty then only it needs to search with that field along with other fields.

Comment: Another question: Are these all the properties of your entity? With the code shown, the _id_ property will be the id used in Elasticsearch, and you will never get more than one document back, because you cannot store multiple documents with the same id.

Comment: Oh actually sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. `id` is the primary key. And `n_id` is just a normal id that is duplicated.

Comment: Having an Optional as an argument is often considered a code-smell. You already know that you have to make some sort of changes if the Optional is empty, so it's better to be explicit about it. See for example recipe 15 in this great article https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/the-java-optional-class-11-more-recipes-for-preventing-null-pointer-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this using a `CriteriaQuery` (`operations` is an `ElasticsearchOperations` implementation injected in your class):

```java
    List<Sample> getAll(String n_id, Optional<String> b_ref, Optional<String> r_ref, List<Status> statuses) {

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria("nid").is(n_id).and("status").in(statuses);

        if (b_ref.isPresent()) {
            criteria = criteria.and("b_ref").is(b_ref.get());
        }

        if (r_ref.isPresent()) {
            criteria = criteria.and("r_ref").is(r_ref.get());
        }

        SearchHits<Sample> searchHits = operations.search(new CriteriaQuery(criteria), Sample.class);

        // to only get the objects without hit information
        return searchHits.stream().map(SearchHit::getContent).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.